# if(window.jQuery) returns false after loading jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JavaScript snippet, which I run in Developer tools console after opening a new tab in Google Chrome with http://example.com

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(jq);

if (window.jQuery) {
    window['jqy'] = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert('jQuery is loaded');
}
else {
    alert('jQuery not loaded');
}
```

It alerts jQuery not loaded for the first time, even when I see that the `<script>` is added to the DOM. Why?

Comment: Because jQuery is not loaded by the time you make this check. You don't think library loads immediately, right? Appending new script to head doesn't make entire JS loop wait until it downloads.

Comment: @dfsq So how do I wait in code until the library loads?

Comment: use jquery ready or $(function(){});

Comment: All dynamically added scripts are loaded asynchronously. If you want to be notified about the script being loaded, you've to add an onload listener to the script element, and do what ever you need in the load handler.

Comment: @NitinDhomse I cannot use jQuery as I am exactly waiting for it to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the script will load in an async manner and will take a while to load completely after the script tag creation.

The alert method is executed just after the addition of script tag.

To achieve something like this you need a callback which will execute after the script is loaded completely.

Maybe something like this?

```js
function loadScript(url, callback) {
  var e = document.createElement("script");
  e.src = url;
  e.type = "text/javascript";
  e.addEventListener('load', callback);
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
}

loadScript("https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js", function() {
  // This callback will fire once the script is loaded
  if (window.jQuery) {
    window['jqy'] = jQuery.noConflict();
    alert('jQuery is loaded');
  } else {
    alert('jQuery not loaded');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Each Method in the javascript can take some time to complete the desired task allocated to it. Even appendChild function also will take some time to execute the method to complete.

But system won't wait for the task to complete and execute the next line. Because of that for the first time alert is coming with the jquery not loaded.

But if you execute the same function in the console again without loading it will alert you as a jquery is loaded because appendchild method completed his task successfully.

To overcome this issue need to add the task as a callback function. But append child is not having any callback function. So we need to use the setTimeOut function to solve this issue.